# Changing default colour of actionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i am trying to change the colour of default action-bar that appears just before launching activity.I am using sherlockacionbar and have to do as below [image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064411/change-actionbarsherlock-background-color

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865914/how-to-change-the-color-of-actionbar-actionbarsherlock